# Find duplicate elements in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, duplicates

I have a lists:

```
nums = [1, 2, 3, 1, 5, 2, 7, 11]
```

I am trying to make a function that returns how many times each number appears in the lists. Output may look like:

```
1 occurred 2 times
2 occurred 2 times
3 occurred 1 time
5 occurred 1 time
...
...
```

This is what I have tried so far:
-Create dictionary for each element in list
-Have nested loop go through every element and check it against every other element
-If elements match add one to the dictionary key of that element

The problem:
Everytime it loops through, it redetects the same elements. Therefore however many of a certain element there is, instead of being added by 1, it is raised by the n power

```
Enter integers between 1 and 100: 5 2 41 4 5 2 2 4
4 occurs 4 times
2 occurs 9 times
41 occurs 1 times
5 occurs 4 times
```

code:

```
def main():
    original_nums = input("Enter integers between 1 and 100: ")
    nums = [i for i in original_nums.split()]
    my_dict = {}

    for i in nums:
        my_dict[i] = 0

    for i in nums:
        for j in nums:
            if i == j:
                my_dict[i] += 1

    for i in my_dict:
        print(i,"occurs",my_dict[i],"times")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Counter](http://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) is all you need

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter([1, 2, 3, 1, 5, 2, 7, 11])
Counter({1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 1, 5: 1, 7: 1, 11: 1})
```

**Or** you can just fix your code like this

```
def main():
    original_nums = input("Enter integers between 1 and 100: ")
    nums = [i for i in original_nums.split()]
    my_dict = {}

    for i in nums:
        my_dict[i] = my_dict.get(i, 0) + 1
        # or .setdefault(i, 0) instead of .get(i, 0)
        # setdefault is generally faster

    for i in my_dict:
        print(i, 'occurs', my_dict[i], 'times')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Runtime:

```
Enter integers between 1 and 100: 5 5 5 5 1 2 3 3 3 
1 occurs 1 times
2 occurs 1 times
3 occurs 3 times
5 occurs 4 times
```

Comment: Problem with counter is I can't use the sorted function with it, without turning it into a lists

Comment: @chopperdrawlion4 maybe you want to use http://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common

Comment: Counter is probably better here. Anyway, the two `for i in nums:` can be replaced by one with the body `my_dic[i] = my_dic.get(i, 0) + 1`. The `.get` returns the value at the key `i` or the default (here zero).

Comment: The big difference between `dict.get` and `dict.setdefault` is that `.get` does not modify the dictionary. Say, you want to implement a sparse lookup table. The `.setdefault`, on the other hand, is better when you want to assign mutable object and you want to keep the same instance when modified later -- say `dict.setdefaut(k, []).append(value)`.

Comment: @pepr I know it :) the code with `setdefault` runs slightly faster than code with `get` (at least on my machine)

Comment: @frostnational: I know you know :) That comment was not for you.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use a [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), which essentially does what you're trying to do internally:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> 
>>> nums = [1, 2, 3, 1, 5, 2, 7, 11]
>>> 
>>> counts = Counter(nums)
>>> 
>>> for t in counts.iteritems():
...     print '%d occured %d times' % t
... 
1 occured 2 times
2 occured 2 times
3 occured 1 times
5 occured 1 times
7 occured 1 times
11 occured 1 times
```