# Without using Counter(), how to find most common element in a list?

Tags: python, string, list, counter

Without using the `Counter()` class, and instead a normal dictionary, how can I find the most common element(s) in a list?

the given list is:

```
my_list = ['duck', 'duck', 'horse', 'goose', 'bird', 'goose']
```

and I would like the output to be something like this

```
most_common: duck, goose
```

whereby the elements with the same count will both appear if they are both the max, and then they can be output as a string and not their own list.

Comment: Should be possible in many ways.  Could you share your thoughts?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22442314/2301450. And Counter isn't a function, it's a class.

Comment: And why don't you want to use Counter?

Comment: @JayanthKoushik obviously some kind of homework

Comment: Did I edit it well enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use normal dictionary to gather the count like this

```
count_dict = {}
for item in my_list:
    count_dict.setdefault(item, 0)
    count_dict[item] += 1
```

And then find the maximum value like this

```
maxi = max(count_dict[item] for item in count_dict)
```

Now its just a matter of finding elements with the speicific count

```
print([item for item in count_dict if count_dict[item] == maxi])
# ['goose', 'duck']
```

Instead of using plain dictionary, you can use `collections.defaultdict` as well,

```
from collections import defaultdict
count_dict = defaultdict(int)
for item in my_list:
    count_dict[item] += 1
```

Rest of the idea will be the same.

If you want to print the strings concatenated together, then you can do

```
print("Most Common:", ", ".join([item for item in count_dict if count_dict[item] == maxi]))
# Most Common: duck, goose
```

Comment: You can just do max(counter, key=lambda x: counter[x]) to find the element.

Comment: Of course, that won't find all the maximum values.

Comment: Don't call your dict `counter`.  It might confuse the OP.

Comment: @devnull Right, Updated it :)

Comment: @thefourtheye Thanks! So I get it to count properly (maxi) but the print function gives me a invalid syntax error. I know my questions are those a troglodyte would ask, but I've only been programming with Python for a couple months. I appreciate all the help as I learn this new language!

Comment: @user3522321 Which version of Python do you use?

Comment: @user3522321 In Python 3.x, `print` is a function. So, you might want  to do like this `print(...)`. Please try this

Comment: @thefourtheye I had modified it to print(("Most Common: ", item for item in count_dict if count_dict[item] == maxi))
but it moves my cursor to the 'for' part and says error

Comment: @user3522321 Good try :) But, since we use list comprehension, it should be `print("Most Common:", [item for item in count_dict if count_dict[item] == maxi])`

Comment: @thefourtheye Ohmygoodness! I had tried every other combination! That works!! Thanks you so much :) Can I ask one more question while you're here?
My output is Most Common: ['Limpets', 'Mussels'] 
is there a way to format it to read just Most Common: Limpets, Mussels without the brackets? I tried formatting the output into a new list, but it demanded integers and not stings?

Comment: @user3522321 Since what you have is a list of strings, you can join them like this `",".join([i for i in count_dict if count_dict[i] == maxi]))`

Comment: @thefourtheye Well now, that just went and mushed everything together lol
my output was LimpetsMost Common: Mussels

Comment: @thefourtheye Thanks for all your help :) Seems this arena can be quite harsh to the newcomer, thanks for being patient with me!!

Answer (score 0):

First of all it is bad habit of using predefined class name to object , you used `list` in your question .

```
>>> lst = ['duck','duck','horse','goose','bird','goose']
>>> temp=set(lst)
>>> result={}
>>> for i in temp:
     result[i]=lst.count(i)


>>> result
{'goose': 2, 'horse': 1, 'bird': 1, 'duck': 2}
>>>
```